# react js rendering images using props in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render images from my server ftp using props in React JS.

I have like:

```
render(){
    console.log(this.props.product.image)   //Which gives me the product image name properly
    return(
   <div className={this.props.openModal ? "modal-wrapper active" : "modal-wrapper"}>
    <div className="modal" ref="modal">
      <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this)}>&times;</button>
      <div className="quick-view">
        <div className="quick-view-image"><img src={`${this.props.product.image}`} alt={this.props.product.name +'  image'}/></div>
        <div className="quick-view-details">
          <span className="product-name">{this.props.product.name}</span>
          <span className="product-price">{this.props.product.price}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

In the log i am getting the image name, but why not the same in the img src attribute.

I tried to give the same line in src like i have given in console.

But just gave a try like:

[image]

Log data:

[image]

Comment: Why the back-tic-$-{ around `this.props.product.image`?

Comment: You shouldn't need the template string.  You can just use `<img src={this.props.product.image} />` and that should give you the the `src` you are expecting.  Depending on the current url path, you may need to add to the front of the image path.

Comment: you need to append the path to access the image. If the image is in current working directory then use './' to append to the filename.

Comment: Yes @Davin, im able to get the filename from just this.prop.product.image only in the console, but if i include inside the src attr, im not getting

Comment: @TarangDave yes, except this will pull the image path from the browser so if the image is being served from the root directory then a `/` should be at the beginning.  Otherwise, the path to the image directory needs to be added: `/images/ + this.props.product.image`, for example.

Comment: @stack200s mate, the filename showing in the console is just the name. Its not the path to where the image is stored. Locate where your file is stored on the server. Try to give the complete path in src. Your <img> won't be able to get the image unless the entire filepath is served.

Comment: Ok thanks, have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i updated the full path, now image is rendering.

```
 <img src={'http://localhost:5000/images/products/'+this.props.image}
```